# How to list all methods annotated with specific annotation in "src/test" path using Reflections?

Tags: java, annotations

I have two annotations: @Feature and @Scenario.

The @Feature annotation I'm using it in the Controller methods (GET/PUT/POST... in path "src/main/java...").

The @Scenario annotation I'm using it in my unit tests (Controller or Service tests in path "src/test/java...").

I need to list all methods annotated with both annotations, so I created a class in "src/main/java..." path to do that.
I'm able to find all methods annotated with @Feature, but I can't find the methods annotated with @Scenario.
How can I do that?

I tried to do that using [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library

```
final Set<Method> features = new Reflections("com.myprefix", new MethodAnnotationsScanner()).getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Feature.class);
final Set<Method> scenarios = new Reflections("com.myprefix", new MethodAnnotationsScanner()).getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Scenario.class);
```

"features" returns all methods annotated with @Feature, but "scenarios" returns empty

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a JUnit test to solve your problem? Here is one that should work for your problem:

```
@Test
public void findMethodsannotatedWith(){
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false /* don't exclude Object.class */), new ResourcesScanner()
            , new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
        .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("com.myprefix"))));

    final Set<Method> features = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Feature.class);
    final Set<Method> scenarios = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Scenario.class);
}
```